# ffmpeg merge audio and video without gap

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to successfully merge video and audio file with ffmpeg.

This is the command line I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:06:53 -t 00:00:11 -i /var/www/pl_addons/movies/demo/demo.mkv -ss 00:06:53 \
                -t 00:00:11 -i /var/www/pl/movies/demo/demo.fr.aac \
                -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 \
                -map 1:a:0 /var/www/html/pl/movies/9ddfede916b158b/cuts/XJPYKITNQ9.mkv
```

This seems to work, but I have a little issue:
The times indicated here are just an example; it can start at different times.

The video often starts a few seconds before the sound.
The sound always start at the right time but video often a little bit earlier.

Everything is well sync. The duration is respected for the sound but can be longer because of the earlier start for the video.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

My English is not very good. I hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You're saying the video starts before the sound, but then you write that everything is "well sync(ed)"? Can you confirm that your MKV and AAC files start at the same time? Please also show the full, uncut command line output.

Comment: The video part is longer than the audio part that is why even if the sound start after, the audio and the video are well synced.

Comment: With your command though, you are starting them both at the same time (06:53). It's not really clear what your problem is. Perhaps you can try explaining in other words.

Comment: With this command, I extract a video with no sound at start, then the sound is there, well sync with video. The duration of the video with the sound is well respected and start at the right time but I don't know why I have this short part with no sound at start.